# CSS id don't work

Tags: html, css

I can't see what is wrong with this. I have 2 HTML sheets and a CSS sheet.

The first HTML sheet (`index.html`) is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Olive</h1>
    <a href="page1.html">Enter</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The second HTML sheet (`page1.html`) is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id="prenav">Olive</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the CSS external sheet:

```
body {
background-color: olive;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
font-size: 230px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
}

a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
color: white;
font-size: 100px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#prenav {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
font-size: 50px;
color: white;
}
```

The issue is that the `id` from the second HTML sheet (`page1.html`) doesn't work. I don't know why. I don't know if it's the syntaxis or what.

The body attributes are working in `page1.html`, but the `id` attributes don't. The `<p>` element only appears with any style. Could someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: It works fine on here? http://jsfiddle.net/gdhJq/

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: self closing is missing in your link tag `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

Comment: Make sure to Ctrl+F5 or disable cache while testing.

Comment: @Sachin self-closing doesn't exist in HTML. That's for XML/[X]HTML - the html parser simply ignores the `/` so that it has no effect.

Comment: I did correct the link tag, but it still doesn't work. And I refreshed the page a lot of times, and it's the same.

Comment: I put everything inside a jsfiddle, and it have worked. So what is the problem? My browser? It's Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few tips for debugging... try to make cache refresh few times when you have modified your css styles (with chrome and windows: `ctrl+shift+r`) then if it doesnt work try to use code below and cache refresh again:

```
#prenav {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive !important;
font-size: 50px !important;
color: white !important;
}
```

The `!important` rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
background-color: olive;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
font-size: 230px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
}

a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
color: white;
font-size: 100px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#prenav {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
font-size: 50px;
color: white;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id="prenav">Olive</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit:

Solution was to put .css stylesheet to correct folder.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks man! I have done everything you've said, but it doesn't work. Sincerely, I don't know what's happening. Should I close Google Chrome and run CCleaner?

Comment: try to open it with different browser next (if it works there), clear cache and cookies through options of chrome?

Comment: Thats why it seems like cache issue of your own codes, report back when you have opened your codes with different browser? - not just jsfiddle but page1.html :)

Comment: I've opened it with Chrome, Firefox and IE, but it haven't run in any of them.

Comment: I wont believe it, i pasted my code i am using which works. save it as test.html and open it up.

Comment: Yes, your code did work! You've put the CSS code inside the HTML page, so maybe the issue is with my CSS external sheet?

Comment: Nice! :) place it inside same folder than your html files - should work!

Comment: I finally could find what was the issue! The external CSS sheet was placed in other floder, I don't know why it was placed there! Iwas sure I put it in the same folder! Thanks A LOT for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the issue, but your first line should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you don't declare it properly, your browser could render in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) which can result in all sorts of odd behavior.

Comment: You're right, but I did correct that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct, but maybe the script is any command that changes the style for this id.